# Consider the intergal $I=\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{ax^2+bx+c}dx$, where $a,b,c$ are constants. When does the integral converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Consider the integral $I=\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{ax^2+bx+c}dx$, where $a,b,c$ are constants. When does the integral converge?

As usual, these are alien concepts to me, it gets tough to understand, but I realize, if the integral value is finite, we will have a solution. But, I cannot do anything more.

Comment: Tell us your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I would be grateful if the downvoter could also explain the reason for downvote?

Comment: @Swadhin I downvoted because you show no effort.

Comment: @avid19 I showed my work later on, but I don't think I can do anything more than I said, it looks like a dead end to me.

Comment: Your multiple choices are not rendering for me. I see several unicode stamps (which I assume are minus signs). I'd suggest asking this question without the multiple choices, and just learning from answers that explain in more generality.

Comment: @alex.jordan in that case, I remove the choice on your instructions.

Comment: If the terminology is alien, perhaps it is better to frame your Question around the meaning here, e.g. "does the integral converge"?  The [integral $I$ shown is "improper"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) because its upper limit of integration is $\infty$, so that one needs to define its value as the value of a limit, letting the upper limit of integration tend to infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exponent of the exponential is $ax^2+bx+c=a(x+b/2a)^2-(b^2-4ac)/4a$ for $a\ne 0$.  Thus, the integral becomes

$$\int_1^{\infty} e^{ax^2+bx+c}dx=e^{-(b^2-4ac)/4a}\int_1^{\infty} e^{a(x+b/2a)^2}dx=e^{-(b^2-4ac)/4a}\int_{1+b/2a}^{\infty} e^{ax^2}dx$$

Thus, the integral converges (diverges) for $a<0$ ($a>0$) for all $b$ and $c$.

For $a=0$, the exponent of the exponential is $bx+c$.  Thus, the integral becomes

$$\int_1^{\infty} e^{bx+c}dx=e^{c}\int_1^{\infty} e^{bx}dx$$

and the integral converges (diverges) for $b<0$  ($b\ge 0$).

Comment: I do not understand why, would you explain please?

Comment: I did not downvote I think...

Comment: @Swadhin Let me know how I can improve my answer.

Comment: @Dr.MV , how about this, it easier to explain using this, since integral is essential area under curve for $1 \to \infty$ ^^ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pomogre3dg

Comment: No, its fine, I understand it very very clearly now. Thanks!

Comment: @Swadhin You're welcome.  My pleasure!!

Answer (score 3):

A function that tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ cannot be integrable over $(1,\infty)$. Therefore either $a<0$, or $a=0$ and $b<0$, or $a=b=0$, as these are the only ways to make the function bounded as $x\to\infty$.

$a=b=0$ leaves you with a constant function, clearly *not* integrable over $(1,\infty)$.

$a=0$ and $b<0$ leaves you with an *integrable* function over $(1,\infty)$, seen by just writing an antiderivative and seeing its limit as $x\to\infty$.

$a<0$ leaves you with an *integrable* function over $(1,\infty)$, because for large enough $x$ you have a positive function even smaller than the $a=0$ and $b<0$ case.